# cannot access url in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I try to access an url with spring mvc application but I got error 404 :
**http://localhost:8181/201701241113-spring-pratique/welcome.htm**

[image: Project structure]

I have 3 xml configuration files :

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    </web-app>
```

**court-service.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="reservationService" class="com.cozla.service.ReservationServiceImpl" />
```

**court-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean name="/welcome.htm" class="com.cozla.web.WelcomeController" />

    <bean name="/reservationQuery.htm" class="com.cozla.web.ReservationQueryController">
        <property name="reservationService" ref="reservationService" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>Court Reservation System</display-name>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/court-servlet.xml;/WEB-INF/court-service.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>201701241113-spring-pratique</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>201701241113-spring-pratique</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I can display the "welcome page"

**The controller code**

```
package com.cozla.web;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

public class WelcomeController extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {

        Date today = new Date();
        return new ModelAndView("welcome", "today", today);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share controller code.

Comment: I shared the controller code. Thanks for your help !

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Usually we have annotations  in controller for atleast requestMappings. The way you are creating beans and trying to map is looking very false. Please cross check any tutorials!!

Comment: Really? I can't fin any example how to implement Spring-mvc 2.5 with only XML configurations (Without annotations)

Answer (score 0):

If all works fine, then in eclipse sometimes you need to check the following option while adding tomcat server into new workspace. Make sure that under **Server Locations** you need to select **Use Tomcat installation**(second one) in the screenshot below :

[image]

Comment: I've already chosen the second option. Now it tells me that my controller class is not found